# django pagination with random queryset, ?page=1 content different to root

Tags: django

I have a CBV Listview for which I obtain and random queryset and paginate it, but, I see that there seems to a difference in content from `somedomain.com/quiz/1` and `somedomain.com/quiz/1/?page=1`

My Listview looks like so:

```
class Test_ListView1(ListView):
    template_name = "test.html"
    paginate_by = 12
    context_object_name = "test"

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = list(SomeModel.objects.order_by("-created_at").values('id','question_field','some_json'))
        random.shuffle(queryset)
        return queryset[:24]
```

in my urls, I cache my page so that it returns the same value for a certain period (50000sec) of time like so:

```
path('somedomain.com/quiz/1', cache_page(50000)(Test_ListView1.as_view()), name="test1" ),
```

but, I still see a difference between `somedomain.com/quiz/1` and `somedomain.com/quiz/1/?page=1` - they seem to be two different pages..

How do I make them the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4992) Django takes into account query params when construct cache key. You can see source [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8b3e714ecf409ed6c9628c3f2a4e033cbfa4253b/django/utils/cache.py#L324). `request.build_absolute_uri()` is using here which returns full url with query params. That's why `somedomain.com/quiz/1` and `somedomain.com/quiz/1/?page=1` are different pages for cache middleware.

So to fix I suppose you can just add redirect if `page` query parameter not provided, something like this:

```
def get(self, request):
    if not request.GET.get("page"):
        return redirect(reverse('view_name') + '?page=1')
    return super().get(request)
```

Comment: Your solution works like a charm - I did not know about the ticket. Thank you. I have accepted to answer.

Comment: Its very weird.. The same snippet of code which you have posted, works on localhost, but refuses to reditect on production mode :((

Comment: @AJW hm.. is it just not redirecting or showing some error?

Comment: Its very weird - it is the exact same code.. works great on dev (localhost), but does not work in production mode. There is no error erither. it simply takes me to the original page (without the `?page=1`).... Cant for the life of me figure out what it could be. never encountered such a thing. I use `reverse_lazy` instead of `reverse`.. as I said.. it does work on local mode

Comment: @AJW have no idea what could be the reason of it. Do you have logging system? Prbably you could try info logger to check value of `request.GET.get("page")` and `reverse('view_name') + '?page=1'`. Also you can try to change logic like this: `if request.GET.get("page"):` then `return redirect('view_name')`.

Comment: I have logging enabled, and when iam in dev mode, I can see the log file within the `def get`.. BUT, in production mode, there there seems to be no logs, which means it just does not get to the def get() method.. why? I am TOTALLY perplexed!!!!!!!! I REALLY dont understand how this can be possible...in prod mode, I simply do git clone and run.. so there is no change of code whatsoever...

Comment: @AJW are you sure you deployed changes to the prod? Did you restart gunicorn and nginx after git clone repo to production?

Comment: yes, I am 100% sure it is deployed - I even vim'ed the file on the server to check and it reflects the changes.. :((oh man I cant believe this really.. what the F could be wrong!!!! it works totally fine in local dev. I also retsrated my server machine, deleted the repo and recloned it.. just to be sure..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205768/discussion-between-neverwalkaloner-and-ajw).